# Round corner not correct

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wish to draw a round corner but below code seems not as expected. The upper right corner is turn to a wrong direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\def\N{6}
\newcommand{\connect}[2]{
  \path[*->] ($(#1 north)!0.5!(#1 south)$) edge [bend left] (#2);
}
\newcommand{\drawme}[3]{
  \draw[*->,rounded corners=10pt] ($(#1 north)!0.5!(#1 south)$)  |- ++(0,#3) -| (#2);              
}
\newcommand{\annotation}[2] {
  \draw[->] ([yshift=1cm]#1) -- node [above,sloped] {#2} (#1);                
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  list/.style={
    very thick, rectangle split, 
    rectangle split parts=3, draw, 
    rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt,
    inner sep=5pt, text=black,
    rectangle split part fill={blue!20, red!20, blue!20}
  }, 
  ->, start chain=M0 going right,very thick
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} {
    \node[list,on chain] (P\i) {\nodepart{second} $P\i$};
  }

  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,...,\N} {
    \ifthenelse{\i<\N} {
      \connect{P\i.three}{P\j.north west}
      \connect{P\j.one}{P\i.south east}
    }{
      \drawme{P\i.three}{P1.north west}{1cm}
      \drawme{P1.one}{P\i.south east}{-1cm}
    }
  }

  \annotation{P2.north}{begin};
  \annotation{P1.north}{end};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `\drawme` as

```
\newcommand{\drawme}[3]{
  \draw[*->,rounded corners=10pt] ($(#1 north)!0.5!(#1 south)$)  -- ++(0,#3) -| (#2);
}
```

I have changed `|- ++(0,#3)` to `-- ++(0,#3)`

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.multipart,chains,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\def\N{6}
\newcommand{\connect}[2]{
  \path[*->] ($(#1 north)!0.5!(#1 south)$) edge [bend left] (#2);
}
\newcommand{\drawme}[3]{
  \draw[*->,rounded corners=10pt] ($(#1 north)!0.5!(#1 south)$)  -- ++(0,#3) -| (#2);
}
\newcommand{\annotation}[2] {
  \draw[->] ([yshift=1cm]#1) -- node [above,sloped] {#2} (#1);
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  list/.style={
    very thick, rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=3, draw,
    rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=18pt,
    inner sep=5pt, text=black,
    rectangle split part fill={blue!20, red!20, blue!20}
  },
  ->, start chain=M0 going right,very thick
  ]
  \foreach \i in {1,...,\N} {
    \node[list,on chain] (P\i) {\nodepart{second} $P\i$};
  }

  \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,...,\N} {
    \ifthenelse{\i<\N} {
      \connect{P\i.three}{P\j.north west}
      \connect{P\j.one}{P\i.south east}
    }{
      \drawme{P\i.three}{P1.north west}{1cm}
      \drawme{P1.one}{P\i.south east}{-1cm}
    }
  }

  \annotation{P2.north}{begin};
  \annotation{P1.north}{end};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's what I want. :-). but why |- doesn't work?

Comment: @Beatlej Because, you need to go up by  1cm straight and `|-` is not straight, hence confusing `tikz`.